# Linux user cannot read or edit outside their home directory

Tags: linux, users, user-permissions

I was wondering how to setup user accounts on linux where the user cannot read or edit outside their home directory.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Can you be more specific about your requirements and what you're expecting to accomplish? Because it sounds like you're asking how to make an unusable system.

Answer (score 6):

Generally you want to chroot them into their home directory. If you do a google search on something like "linux chroot home directory" You will pull up hundreds of howto's on the subject.

It's just not as easy as running a single command.

Answer (score 1):

Valid question, +1 to remove negative vote. Mike's is the "proper way" to achieve what you seek.

The direct answer (and a PITA way of doing things) is to screw up your system's permissions. You might think that a massive chmod -R 750 * would do it, however then your users will not be able to run programs or read important initialization files in /etc.

What I would do to still grant people access to important info is chmod directories to 751 or 711, which is `drwx--x--x`. This allows people to "execute" a folder, which lets them go into it but they cannot get a directory listing. So if you chmod 751 (or 711) /etc, someone can still read normal files that are 644 if they know these files are there. So you could `cat /etc/hosts` or other important setup files in order to operate as normal.

It's not what I might call the true way (or correct answer), but this is what I would do as a user to share services with other users while still keeping some privacy.

---

Now that I've thought more about this, an actual scenario for this question might be the mildly paranoid virtual host granting occasional ssh access to users. I would try something like `find /etc/ -R -type d -perm 755 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 711` This might actually keep people from snooping around too much. If someone were real good, obviously, they'll guess file names...

Another real case for weird `711` directory permissions is setting up a samba share on a fileserver and still give individual users their own home directories on the share. That gets set as so:

`drwx--S--T.  38 chris   samba  12K 2012-06-14 17:16 chris`